# How do I quickly check if all elements of numpy array are floats?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to write a function F which takes a numpy array with dtype=object, and returns whether all elements of an array are floats, integers, or strings. For example:

```
F(np.array([1., 2.], dtype=object))  --> float
F(np.array(['1.', '2.'], dtype=object))  --> string
F(np.array([1, 2], dtype=object))  --> int
F(np.array([1, 2.], dtype=object))  --> float
F(np.array(['hello'], dtype=object))  --> string

F(np.array([1, 'hello'], dtype=object))  --> ERROR
```

Any ideas how to do that effectively? (== with numpy built-in functions)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want F(np.array([1, 2.], dtype=object)) to throw an error cause of mixing int and float?

Comment: Returning float for F(np.array([1, 2.], dtype=object)) is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the simplest is to run the contents through `np.array` and check the resulting type:

```
a = np.array([1., 2.], dtype=object)
b = np.array(['1.', '2.'], dtype=object)
c = np.array([1, 2], dtype=object)
d = np.array([1, 2.], dtype=object)
e = np.array(['hello'], dtype=object)
f = np.array([1, 'hello'], dtype=object)

>>> np.array(list(a)).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> np.array(list(b)).dtype
dtype('S2')
>>> np.array(list(c)).dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> np.array(list(d)).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> np.array(list(e)).dtype
dtype('S5')
```

It fails to raise an error in case of incompatible types, since that is not numpy's behavior:

```
>>> np.array(list(f)).dtype
dtype('S5')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Raising an error is actually easy -- just do np.all(new_array == old_array)

Comment: FYI `list(array_to_check)` makes a copy of `array_to_check`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the most efficient with object management, but how about:

```
def F(a):
    unique_types = set([type(i) for i in list(a)])
    if len(unique_types) > 1:
        raise ValueError('data types not consistent')
    else:
        return unique_types.pop()
```